# Is there any tutorial available to run Karate Gatling tests in Docker Container with gradle build?

Tags: docker, karate

We are planning to run Karate Gatling tests in Docker Container with Gradle build but I didn't find any resources related to this in the net. I tried the Karate github but it is showing with the Maven instead of gradle. Please help me out.

Both my Karate and Gatling are from open source not enterprise versions.

Help of Karate Gatling in Docker with Gradle

Comment: I can only point you to this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#gradle and I assume if you use a gradle ready docker container you can get it to work